# Distinguish function called by event or programaticly

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

So assume this function :

```
Private Function appendText() As Boolean Handles weComs.WriteChat
   if(Called by event)
     'do something
   else
     'do something

   Return Nothing
End Function
```

So yea, that's about it, I want to know if it's possible for the function or method to know if he have been called by the event or by me somewhere

Comment: why not have `appendText` and the other code call a routine to so the things common to both?  most events though use a `sender as object` param to know who called it.

Comment: Well yea I could use a sender, but I was wondering like without the sender like the property `obj.invokeRequired`

Comment: `sender` is obviously important in this case. even better have the event call a procedure which does the heavy lifting for `appendText` and call that from the other code as well, that way the event code can do anything special when actually invoked as an actual event.

Comment: Not possible. An event calls a handler, which is nothing more than a regular sub. If you provide a good example of why you would need such behavior, we could assist you better. Regarding a suggestion to add a sender parameter - please consider that you can also call this sub and pass a sender in code, same way as an event would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be using a sender. But failing that, pass it in as a parameter.

```
Private Function appendText_Event() As Boolean Handles weComs.WriteChat
    Return AppendText(True)
End Function

Private Function appendText() As Boolean
    Return AppendText(False)
End Function

Private Function AppendText(CalledByEvent as Boolean) As Boolean
   if(CalledByEvent)
     'do something
   else
     'do something

   Return Nothing
End Function
```